# Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

In IE8, my menu script doesn't seem to go down well. But after much searching i can't figure out why it's throwing errors like:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined 
site.js, line 5 character 5
```

My Script is:

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    [].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor){
      var open = false;
      anchor.onclick = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!open){
          this.classList.add('close');
          open = true;
        }
        else{
          this.classList.remove('close');
          open = false;
        }
      };
    });
```

This script handles my mobile navigation, but as i am still learning, i can't figure this one out. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Actually, a lot of those aren't available in IE8, `classList` only works properly in IE11 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not supported in IE8.

Since you have tagged the question with jQuery use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate an array.

Using jQuery this can be written as

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('close')
})
```

A vanila script solution can be

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function handler(e) {
    if (/\bclose\b/.test(this.className)) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(/\bclose\b/, '');
    } else {
        this.className += ' close';
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        anchor[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    } else {
        anchor[i].attachEvent('onclick', handler);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G9gZ2/)

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I need to read up on this some more, i think i have a lot to learn. Big thanks!